# Convert code from Objective C to Swift for FactualSDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sdk, factual

This is my first question on Stack Overflow, I was integrating the Factual SDK in my app using swift. I successfully created a bridgeheader for the framework but could not figure out how to convert this line of code in order to set the authKey and ID in swift. Thanks in advance!!

```
FactualAPI* _apiObject = [[FactualAPI alloc] initWithAPIKey:@"yourkey" secret:@"yoursecret"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
let _apiObject = FactualAPI(APIKey:"yourkey" secret:"yoursecret")
```

I tested it and its working fine.